# Can we call different container with in stored proc of one container in Cosmos db?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have two containers in cosmos db. Assume container 1 and container 2. I want to create stored proc in container 1. Can I call container2 with in stored proc which got created under container 1?

Comment: Hence, requests made within stored procedures execute in the same scope of a database session. -- from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/stored-procedures), and what you can do is create multiple sp in each container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use stored procedures in DocumentDB that use multiple collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081301/how-can-i-use-stored-procedures-in-documentdb-that-use-multiple-collections)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. The scope of a Stored Procedure is the current logical partition of a particular container.

> Stored procedures are associated with an Azure Cosmos container and stored procedure execution is scoped to a logical partition key. [[source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs)